# How to center this container of unknown size?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following CSS/Markup

http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/

```
.res-tile-wrap {padding-bottom:25px;}
.res-tile
{
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    width:36px; height:34px; margin: 25px 0 0 25px; float:left; position:relative;
}

<div class="res-tile-wrap">
    <div class="res-tile">1</div>
    <div class="res-tile">2</div>
    <div class="res-tile">...etc</div>
</div>
```

`res-tile-wrap` will contain an unknown number of tile divs. Is there a way to center `res-tile-wrap` or give the appearance that it is centered given that I do not want to give it a specific width because I want as many tiles per row as the screen will allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inner divs you can use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and as inner content is behaving like an inline element you can center it in the container `res-tile-wrap` with `text-align:center` :

```
res-tile-wrap {
    padding-bottom:25px;
    text-align:center;
}

.res-tile{
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    width:36px; height:34px; margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Example with 4 inner divs**](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/3/)
[**Example with 11 inner divs**](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.res-tile-wrap{text-align:center}
.res-tile
{
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    width:36px; height:34px; margin: 25px 0 0 25px; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You don't need position:relative or float at all. Make tiles display: inline-block, so they will behave like "text" and text-align:center the container.

Answer (score 1):

While @Noyulysses answer works well for centering along the X-axis **(and I'm assuming that's what your question was asking about)** it's nearly impossible to both vertically and horizontally center an element with an unspecified width and height without using JavaScript.

You can center something in the exact center of the screen with something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function ()
{
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}

$('.downBig').center();
$(window).resize(function(){
   $('.downBig').center();
});
```

I got this function from another SO answer somewhere... I can't find it at the moment but when I do I'll link to it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sf7H4/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

To center a div of an unknown width simply apply `display: table` to it, with `margin: 0 auto`.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/8/

```
.res-tile-wrap {
    padding-bottom:25px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will, however, it won't work if divs are not filling viewport's width, [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/11/). They are centered in the viewport, but not in the container. No offense, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 easy ways :

1) display:table : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/7/)**

```
html{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
body  {
   display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

2) display:flex; : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/6/)**

```
html, body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    height:100%;
    align-items:center;
}
body > div {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.res-tile-wrap
{
width: 100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

hand type: untested

Answer (score 0):

Another option http://jsfiddle.net/3SNm8/12/

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
.res-tile-wrap {
    padding-bottom:25px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```